# MATLAB Guide handles between Callback and Function

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a MATLAB Guide project. I have a mixture of regular functions and callbacks in the same `.m` file.

I call a function from within a callback and as that functions runs through a `for` loop I wish for a string box to be updated. Here is an example:

From a callback (extract shown) I call this function:

```
[color] = get_color(images, handles);
set(handles.ProcessImage, 'string', 'Processing Complete');
```

The `get_color` function is located within the same `.m` file

```
function [color_corrections] = get_color(images, handles) 

[n, ~, ~, ~] = size(images); % Find the number of images

for imgIdx=1:n % For each image

    set(handles.ProcessImage, 'String', 'Processing Image #');

end
end
```

The problem is that `handles.ProcessImage` does not get updated during the `for` loop, yet it gets written to `'Processing Complete'` when it returns from the function.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
TommyMac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a tight loop, the calculations take precedence so Matlab ends up not bothering to update the GUI until it has time again, i.e. once the loop's finished. You can force a GUI update by calling [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) after updating the string, like so:

```
set(handles.ProcessImage, 'String', 'Processing Image #');
drawnow; % force the new string to be rendered
```

Be aware that you *could* take a massive performance hit, if the code in the loop is short but has many iterations. If there are relatively few iterations but each one takes a long time, you shouldn't notice the difference.

Comment: Hi, Everything is being called and working correctly. Is there anyway to update during the loop? maybe using a threading approach?

Comment: @user3238504 Sorry, I realise I kind of hid the answer in all that explanation. Updated.